# can not serialize a nested struct to json

Tags: go

i want to serialize a struct to json, i wrote below code, but always return empty, did not figure it out.

you can try below code here: http://play.golang.org/p/Y7Zv_aFbqs

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    //"io/ioutil"
)

type Configitem struct {
    local_address string
    local_port    int
    method        string
    password      string
    server        string
    server_port   string
    timeout       int
}

type GuiConfig struct {
    configs []*Configitem
    index   int
}

func main() {

    item1 := &Configitem{
        local_address: "eouoeu",
        local_port:    111,
        method:        "eoeoue",
        password:      "ouoeu",
        server:        "oeuoeu",
        server_port:   "qoeueo",
        timeout:       3333,
    }

    config1 := &GuiConfig{
        index:   1,
        configs: []*Configitem{item1}}

    fmt.Println(config1.configs[0].local_address)

    res2, err := json.Marshal(config1)
    check(err)
    fmt.Println(string(res2))
}

func check(e error) {
    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }
}
```

always return {},  i checked this link http://blog.golang.org/json-and-go, did not know why? what's wrong to my code.

Comment: yes, i do did some search but did not find yet, thanks for remind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `json.Marshal` is in another package, it only has access to exported fields.  If you export the fields it works: http://play.golang.org/p/EMGm5-hs8g

Your other option is to implement the MarshalJson interface yourself (if you don't want to export the fields): http://play.golang.org/p/9gGOBuGbVu

Comment: I think its time we closed these as duplicates now.. this "error" pops up a few times a week now.

Comment: o shoooooot, i just start write go today, i forgot low case means "private". thanks a lot.